# Working android project stopped working after updating android tools from r19 to r20

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

I came to a new project which have been developed for a quite long time.

My co-workers have the exact same codebase but I had to install Eclipse and the ADT plugin. My co-workers have r19 of android tools and android platform-tools r11. I've android tools r20 and platform tools r12.

Now I get this error message after running the software.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{
com.project.package/com.project.package.MyActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.project.package.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClass Loader
```

So our manifest looks something like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStyle" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="locale" >
```

etc.

I'm using Eclipse Classic Indigo (v. 3.8).

Any idea what has happened?

Comment: i also update to r20 , but my projects are working fine. There is no r19. We have r18 then r20. Even though try to clean and update SDK & ADT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem after I updated to SDK Tools r20. Then I realised I had not updated ADT to r20 and, once I did so, then the problem went away.

I'm using Indigo (3.7.2).

Comment: My problem was that I was missing one library for some reason. After I installed that plugin and updated the IDE and ADT it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project. I had the same problem, but it went away after cleaning.